# Does it sound strange to say "I waited until the train had left the station."?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, tense

I learned that the past perfect tense is normally used to express a past action that happened before another past action.

For example, "*When we arrived the film had started*"

The film started before we arrived.

[This dictionary says](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/until):

> You can also use the past perfect tense with until:
>
> I waited until the train had left the station.

I feel it is better to say "*I had been waiting until the train left the station*" or "*By the time the train left the station, I had been waiting for hours*"

I don't understand this strange sentence "*I waited until the train had left the station.*"

Comment: Past perfect is supposed to make things clearer. "I waited until the train had left the station" doesn't say much more than "I waited until the train **left** the station."

Comment: Why do you do this?. Those are just two different sentences, neither of which is better than the other. Any active verb can take any number of tenses and the meaning is not exactly the same.

Comment: The sentence suggests to me that the speaker stood on the station platform until the train had gone. Maybe they had been expecting to meet someone arriving on that train who had not appeared, so they wanted to be absolutely certain that person wasn't there before leaving the station.

Comment: @Lambie, because I don't understand "I waited until the train had left the station." I thought it might mean "I had been waiting until the train left the station". I am a nonnative speaker. If you don't put yourself in a nonnative speaker’s shoes, you will never understand why they ask these questions. So, put yourself in a person’s shoes before you criticize him. I guess you are the one who gave me the down-vote

Comment: I anwered the question after he had left the room. I had been answering until he left the room. You'd be wrong about the non-native speaker part of your comment. I understand exactly. I speak four languages but I **never** ask questions to try and trip up those who help me.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - if I had to wait until the train left the station I could deem my wait  to be over the moment the train doors closed and it started to move, but if I had to wait until the train had left the station, my wait was over when the train was no longer in the station (its tail end had passed the end of the platform).

Comment: Tom, it wasn't Lambie who gave you the down-vote.

Comment: You need to provide more context than just one random sentence. "I had been waiting until the train left the station" might make sense as part of a narrative, but we don't normally use past perfect unless we also use another past tense in the same sentence or a nearby sentence, e.g. "I had been waiting until the train left the station, so I was able to see her get off the train before it left."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for your solidarity.

Comment: I've added a downvote. Questions asking whether complex verb forms are "okay" are mostly pointless anyway, but they're *completely* pointless unless we have a full context *And* ideally, something from the OP explaining why they don't think they should use a simpler verb form. There's rarely any *requirement* to use the Perfect form in "to wait" + "until" contexts, but there are certainly contexts where the Perfect just sounds weird *"I waited until he **had** asked before I stepped in to lend a hand"* just sounds stupid to me, but Simple Past (without ***had***) is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of your example sentence is:

> I began waiting, then the train left the station, *then I stopped waiting*.

Your own sentences with "had been waiting" don't have the same meaning.

As you correctly mentioned, past perfect is used to refer to an event in the past that happens before another event in the past. That's the case in the original sentence, but it's hard to see because the simple past event is only *implied*, not directly stated.

With the structure, *[ X-ed + "until" + past perfect ]*, "stop X-ing" is the *implied* simple past event which happens after the "until" clause. In your example sentence, "stopped waiting" is a simple past event that happens after the train leaves the station.

Here's a somewhat clearer example of the same thing:

> I **didn't move** until the train had left the station.

In this version, it's clearer what the implied simple past action is --move-- but the sentence still does not directly state that I moved.

Comment: This is what I want to know. Other answers don't say which action happens which, which confused me.

Answer (score 0):

The present-tense form of this is

> I'm wating until the train has left the station.

So "has left" gets "shifted backwards" into "had left":

> I waited until the train had left the station

If the present tense form was

> I'm waiting until the train leaves the station.

then "leaves" gets back-shifted to "left", and we would say

> I waited until the train left the station.

The difference in meaning here is very slight: the second suggests that the speaker stopped waiting *as soon as* the train left the station, whereas in the first version the speaker might have waited a little longer. But in most cases, either version would be OK.

Comment: There is no back-shifting. There is simply a simple past tense used. Backshifting is this: "I spoke Turkish when I was younger". "She said she had spoken Turkish, etc."

Answer (score 0):

OP writes "I don't understand this strange sentence":

> I waited until the train had left the station.

The perfect expresses on a semantic level the idea of 'action completed' and that idea can be converted semantically to a time-point inasmuch as actions occur in time and their completion serves as a marker. At some point in time, the train's departure from the station is understood to be complete.

The verb **wait** is continuative, atelic.  We can wait **until** some point-in-time.  Thus:

> I waited until the train had left the station.

Comment: I don't agree that "the perfect expresses ... the idea of 'action completed'". The fact that "perfect" and "continuous" can be used separately or together seems to me to disprove the claim. More controversially, I believe that the special semantics of the "perfect" (present relevance) apply only to the present perfect (including the present perfect continuous), and all the other so-called perfect constructions (such as _had been_, _will have been_, _having been_, _to have been_) are not in fact perfect, but simply past relative to some specified or implied point in time.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "can be used separately or together".

Comment: I did it. I have done it. I was doing it. I have been doing it. Four combinations.

Comment: I still don't understand. Those are four different statements. How are they "combinations"?

Comment: The first uses neither perfect nor continuous. The second uses perfect. The third uses continuous. The fourth uses perfect and continuous, and certainly doesn't imply completion.

Comment: The perfect in combinationg with **been** + present participle does not express completion.  But many who study the English language regard the present perfect and past perfect with the past participle as expressing completion.  I'm not out on a limb  all by my lonesome in that notion.

Comment: no, you're not. But that formulation doesn't make any sense to me. The simple past can express completion, so whatever it is that the present perfect expresses, it is not just completion (and in my view, as I explained, it doesn't necessarily express even that).

Comment: But when *inchoative* verbs are involved the simple past doesn't express the notion of completion as clearly as the perfect.  *The train departed* could refer to it  in the act of pulling away. *The train had departed* refers to it as "gone".  It's a semantic perspective, one that is not necessarily clearly definable temporally and spatially.

Answer (score 0):

While all express the fact that you waited, the emphasis on different aspects can make the narrative more vivid or highlight specific meanings for the listener.
In my view, these sentences essentially have little difference.